# Laravel Swapping interface dependancies

Tags: php, laravel

I've been learning a lot about **coding to an interface** instead of coding to a concrete class. 
Now i'm wondering if the following approach is good practice.

Let's say i have a Notifier class using the following structure

```
-app
    --acme
        Notifiers
                - MailNotifier
                             -MailNotifier.php
                - NotifierInterface.php
                - NotifierServiceProvider.php
```

Is this good practice if later i want to add a different sort of notifier? Like a Text notifier for example.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your question about folder structure?, or namespaces? Its hard to tell

Comment: short answer.... yes.

Comment: Sorry it's about the idea of having 1 serviceprovider that can swap out concrete classes

Comment: @Notflip OK, then yes - that is pretty much the whole point of interfaces. I was confused because you show your directory structure, which doesnt seem relevant. Showing your class and interface code would make more sense

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's an example for the use of interfaces. If the future class has functionality which can be described with the same function names and structure go for it.